# Browser rendering different width and height than specified css?

Tags: html, css

In my html page I have `header` and `leftpane` as a `div`. The height of `hedaer` is `116px`, and width of `leftpane` is `181px`. When I inspect my page with `chrome-developer-tool`, it shows me that height and width `98.36px` and `165.41px` respectively instead of original specified in css.

The following image shows the problem with height
[image: height problem]

The following image shows the problem with width.
[image: width problem]

here is relavant css

```
.dashboard-header {
  background: #000000;
  height: 116px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.dashboard-leftpane {
  width: 181px;
  background: #000000;
  height: 100%;
}
```

corresponding html code

```
  <div class="input-search">
    <img class="imgage-search" src="search.svg" alt="Grace Logo">
    <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="" style="border:none; background: #FAFAFA; flex-grow: 2;">
    <img class="imgage-search" src="filter.svg" alt="">
  </div>


  <div class="profile-menu">
    <span class="profile-menu-name">USER</span>
    <img src="arrow_drop_down.svg" alt="">
  </div>
```

```
<div class="dashboard-leftpane">

    <div class="giraffe-list">
      <div class="giraffe-list-item">
          <span class="giraffe-item-name">ITEM1</span>
      </div>

      <div class="giraffe-list-item">
          <span class="giraffe-item-name">ITEM2</span>
      </div>

      <div class="giraffe-list-item">
          <span class="giraffe-item-name">ITEM3</span>
      </div>

      <div class="giraffe-list-item">
          <span class="giraffe-item-name">ITEM4</span>
      </div>

      <div class="giraffe-list-item">
          <span class="giraffe-item-name">ITEM5</span>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes, please provide example code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't know if this can be but make sure you have `box-sizing: border-box` on your divs.

If that doesn't fix it, probably it can be because of `display: flex;`

It's necessary to use `display: flex;` ?

Comment: It is not necessary to use `flex`, but lay-outing things with flex is much more easier for me.

Comment: Well, don't know what to say. I'm not familiar with flex, never need it :) ... So, the flex it's the problem, isn't it ?